# Test try-catch on Express API with mocha, chai, chai-http and sinon

Tags: express, try-catch, integration-testing, sinon, chai-http

I have an API app created with Express with this function on a controller

```
/** UserController.ts */ 
--------------------------

  public static get = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      const user = await UserModel.findById(<<id>>)
 
      if (user) {
        res.status(200).json(<I200Response>{ msg: 'user data', data: user })
      }
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).json(<I500Response>{ error: e.message })
    }
  }
```

I am trying to test 'catch block' works stubbing with sinon but I don't get it. This is one of the hundreds of tests I tried:

```
/** User.specs.ts */
---------------------

  it('Internal server error', async () => {
    const stubReq = chai.request(BASE)
    const stub = sinon.stub(stubReq, 'get').throws(new Error('stub: Internal server error'))

    const r = await request.get(API.info).set('Authorization', userToken)
    stub.reset()

    expect(r).to.have.status(500)
    return expect(r.body).to.have.property('error').that.is.equal('stub: Internal server error')
  })
```

But the response has a status 200 and gets required data.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should stub `UserModel.findById` method with a rejected promise using `sinon.js`.

E.g.

`UserController.ts`:

```js
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { UserModel } from './UserModel';

type I500Response = any;
type I200Response = any;

export class UserController {
  public static get = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      const user = await UserModel.findById(1);

      if (user) {
        res.status(200).json(<I200Response>{ msg: 'user data', data: user });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).json(<I500Response>{ error: e.message });
    }
  };
}
```

`UserModel.ts`:

```js
export class UserModel {
  public static findById(id: number) {
    return { id, name: 'real username' };
  }
}
```

`app.ts`:

```js
import express from 'express';
import { UserController } from './UserController';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.get('/user/:id', UserController.get);

export { app };
```

`app.test.ts`:

```js
import chai, { expect } from 'chai';
import chaiHttp from 'chai-http';
import { app } from './app';
import { UserModel } from './UserModel';
import sinon from 'sinon';

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('62502383', () => {
  it('should pass', (done) => {
    const mError = new Error('stub: Internal server error');
    const findByIdStub = sinon.stub(UserModel, 'findById').rejects(mError);
    chai
      .request(app)
      .get('/user/1')
      .end((err, res) => {
        sinon.assert.calledWith(findByIdStub, 1);
        expect(res).to.have.status(500);
        expect(err).to.be.null;
        expect(res.body.error).to.be.equal('stub: Internal server error');
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

integration test result:

```sh
  62502383
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (31ms)

-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File               | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files          |   82.35 |        0 |   66.67 |   81.25 |                   
 UserController.ts |   77.78 |        0 |     100 |      75 | 12-13             
 UserModel.ts      |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 3                 
 app.ts            |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Comment: adding a sinon sandbox it works without affecting the rest of the tests. However it is not what I am looking for because although it throws an error, it is not executing UserController.get method and therefore nyc coverage fails.